# How equal_range is making use of heterogeneous comparison?

Tags: c++, equal-range

1. How is `Comp{}` in [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) triggering the Compare operation? Is `Comp{}` indicating a R-Value being created?

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

    struct S
    {
        int number;
        char name;
        // note: name is ignored by this comparison operator
        bool operator< ( const S& s ) const { return number < s.number; }
    };

    int main()
    {
        // note: not ordered, only partitioned w.r.t. S defined below
        const std::vector<S> vec = { {1,'A'}, {2,'B'}, {2,'C'}, {2,'D'}, {4,'G'}, {3,'F'} };

        std::cout << "\n" "Using heterogeneous comparison: ";
        struct Comp
        {
            bool operator() ( const S& s, int i ) const { return s.number < i; }
            bool operator() ( int i, const S& s ) const { return i < s.number; }
        };

        const auto p2 = std::equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(), 2, Comp{});

        for ( auto i = p2.first; i != p2.second; ++i )
            std::cout << i->name << ' ';
    }
   ```

Comment: `Comp{}` is a (default-constructed) temporary.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Could you please elaborate in view of my questions?

Comment: You have 3 different questions. Not sure what you already understand to create an answer to all questions. (that's why one question by question is better).